# Memory leak when showing OpenCV image in Gtk Widget

Tags: opencv, python-3.x, gtk, glib, gdk

I am trying to create a Gtk Widget that you can pass an `OpenCV` image to that will then show it. I have created a class that is inherited from `Gtk.Image` that is used to show the image. You pass the OpenCV image to this class using the `show_frame` method, which then updates the `Gtk.Image` so it shows that image.

I have tested this and it works fine, i.e the image is correctly shown and updated when the `show_frame` method is called. However every time the image is updated, the memory used increases, until there is not enough memory and the program crashes.

I believe this is due to the memory that image is not being freed correctly. I cannot however work out how to fix this. I have tried unreferencing the `gbytes` once a new frame is received but this does not help. The memory only builds up when the `set_from_pixbuf` function is called. If this is commented out the memory usage stays at a constant level.

```
class OpenCVImageViewer(Gtk.Image):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Image.__init__(self)

    def show_frame(self, frame):
        # Convert to opencv BGR to Gtk RGB
        rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # Get details about frame in order to set up pixbuffer
        height = rgb_image.shape[0]
        width = rgb_image.shape[1]
        nChannels = rgb_image.shape[2]

        gbytes = GLib.Bytes.new(rgb_image.tostring())
        pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_bytes(gbytes, GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB, False,
                                                 8, width, height, width*nChannels)

        # Add Gtk to main thread loop for thread safety
        GLib.idle_add(self.set_from_pixbuf, pixbuf)
        GLib.idle_add(self.queue_draw)
```

Comment: Did you try to unref `pixbuf`? (Disclaimer: Not sure whether it will work.)

Comment: @ace Trying to unref the `pixbuf` using `pixbuf.unref()` raises `RuntimeError: This method is currently unsupported`.

Comment: Got the same here, did you find a solution?

Comment: It appears that the leakage only appens if the Gtk.Image is visible. Even if you dispose of the Gtk.Image the memory is not freed.

Answer (score 3):

Well,

I found a solution, but I do not understand why it works: Set the image with a copy of the pixbuffer.

```
 imageWidget.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuffer.copy())
```

I came to this solution after observing that the memory leak disapeared for scaled pixbuffers (i.e. result of `pixbuffer.scale_simple`).

Comment: This indeed keeps the memory usage in check! Do you recon there is much of a performance hit doing this? Essentially we are creating two pixbuffers.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from the PyGTK FAQ, [section 5.17](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq05.017.htp):

> There is a reference cycle between the python wrapper and its underlying C object; this means that the object will not be automatically deallocated when there are no more user references, and you will need the garbage collector to kick in (which may take a few cycles). This occasionally causes the odd problem, such as with pixbufs described in FAQ 8.4

And from [section 8.4](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq08.004.htp):

> The answer is "Interesting GC behaviour" in Python.  Apparently finalizers are not necessarily called as soon as an object goes out of scope.  My guess is that the python memory manager doesn't directly know about the storage allocated for the image buffer (since it's allocated by the gdk) and that it therefore doesn't know how fast memory is being consumed.
>   The solution is to call gc.collect() at some appropriate place.
>
> For example, I had some code that looked like this:
>
> ```
> for image_path in images:
>    pb = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(image_path)
>    pb = pb.scale_simple(thumb_width, thumb_height, gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)
>    thumb_list_model.set_value(thumb_list_model.append(None), 0, pb)
> ```
>
> This chewed up an unacceptably large amount of memory for any reasonable image set.  Changing the code to look like this fixed the problem:
>
> ```
> import gc
>
> for image_path in images:
>    pb = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(image_path)
>    pb = pb.scale_simple(thumb_width, thumb_height, gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)
>    thumb_list_model.set_value(thumb_list_model.append(None), 0, pb)
>    del pb
>    gc.collect()
> ```

I am not exactly sure where you should call the garbage collector in your code (since I don't really know that much Python), but I believe this is the way to solve it.

Comment: I tried this by adding `del pixbuf` and `gc.collect()` to the end of the function but this does not stop the increasing memory usage.